# How to export specific gridview columns to word

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have a gridview which shows the bill of items purchased but there is a link for edit and delete as well so when exporting to word the file is generated but it only shows the  tag nothing else.Here is the export to word code

```
Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.Charset = "";
        string FileName = "CompanyName" + DateTime.Now + ".doc";
        StringWriter strwritter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htmltextwrtter = new HtmlTextWriter(strwritter);
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName);
        gridShowBill.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
        gridShowBill.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
        gridShowBill.RenderControl(htmltextwrtter);
        Response.Write(strwritter.ToString());
        Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to hide those links ? If you want some specific columns to be exported, then you should make a provision in the gridview to select those columns and then can export to word/excel. For More Information..refer the following link...

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-GridView-Export-to-Excel---Hide-Columns.aspx

For Normal Export of Gridview to Word...
Refer the following *link*..It might help you..

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/04/how-to-export-gridview-data-to-excel-or.html

Answer (score 0):

Finally i find the solution to my problem
 row.Cells[4].Visible = false;
 row.Cells[5].Visible = false;
i used the above code to hide the specific columns of the gridview.
more over to hide the header of the above columns i used
 MyGridview.HeaderRow.Cells[4].Visible = false;
 MyGridview.HeaderRow.Cells[5].Visible = false;